# RStudio: simple calculations vs. separator

Tags: r

I often use RStudio for a simple calculations, something like the following

```
> (3.456+4.008)*13000+1000000
[1] 1097032
```

And my question (rather stupid, I assume, but I haven't find an answer) is if it's possible to make the output more friendly? E.g.:

```
> (3.456+4.008)*13000+1000000
[1] 1'097'032
```

Answer (score 0):

At the prompt:

```
?format
```

As an example

```
format(12345.6789, digits=9, decimal.mark=",");
```